# Python noob, i don't know why it is giving SyntaxError: Invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

as the title says, i get a sytax error at

```
temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:] from datetime import date
```

and i am not sure how to fix it, or whats wrong.

```
def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:] from datetime import date
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_f
```

Comment: `from datetime import date` should be at the top of the module. At the very least not inline

Comment: the import statement should be a separate line, and also should be at the top of your file

Comment: Someone dragged the top two lines of code somewhere down (or copy paste error). There are two import statements out of place

Comment: both `from .... import ...` statements are at the wrong place, they need to be at the top of your file, one statement each line. Perhaps you copy/pasted inadvertedly. With an error like this, you have to read each line very carefully and try to understand why Python is complaining - it is always right.

Comment: To echo what other users are saying, [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) is the relevant section in the python official style guidelines. It's worth bookmarking and referencing the PEP8 guidelines

Answer (score 0):

The import statement should be at separate line

```
from datetime import date
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_f
```